# Unable to translate Prism ConfirmationRequest to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, prism, c#-to-vb.net

I use Prism with VB.NET although all the Prism 5 documentation is in C#. I have translated most of the code I have need, but now I am not able to translate the confirmation request code. This is the C# code that appears in Prism documentation:

```
private void RaiseConfirmation()
{
    this.ConfirmationRequest.Raise(
        new Confirmation { Content = "Confirmation Message", Title = "Confirmation" },
        c => { InteractionResultMessage = c.Confirmed ? "The user accepted." : "The user cancelled."; });
}
```

Can anyone help me to translate it to VB.NET, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt, totally untested, and probably with a few typos thrown in:

```
Private Sub RaiseConfirmation()
    Me.ConfirmationRequest.Raise(
        New Confirmation() With {
            .Content = "Confirmation Message", .Title = "Confirmation"
        },
        Sub(c)
            InteractionResultMessage =
                If(c.Confirmed, "The user accepted.", "The user cancelled.")
        End Sub
    )
End Sub
```